# What happened to Sandy from Season 3 Christmas episode?

Tags: character, sitcoms, two-and-a-half-men

Sandy was the cook teacher who was dating Alan and started living with him. Her food led to both Charlie and Alan to gain pot bellies.

I do not remember the episode number but it was themed around Christmas. The immediate episode after that didn't even make any mention of her (like Alan breaking up with her) and both Charlie and Alan were back to their normal self (in case of weight management)

Was that just a one-off Christmas special episode which had no effect on the story continuation?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand....